# Que termo pode traduzir o uso de "dung" em "Their cadavers will dung the orange-trees"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Estou traduzindo um texto em inglês onde o verbo "dung" está sendo usado de um jeito bastante peculiar. Estudando o Oxford English Dictionary, identifiquei uma acepção que parece de acordo:

b. transitive. Of a thing: to serve as fertilizing material for (land, a plant, etc.). Later often (literary and poetic) used hyperbolically of human remains with reference to the aftermath of war or battle. Now rare.

Entre os exemplos dessa acepção, estes são totalmente harmônicos com o que eu estou estudando:

"Their rotten carcasses dung the earth."
"Their cadavers will dung the orange-trees"

Existe algum verbo em português que carrega essa conotação?

No texto que eu estou estudando, durante uma série de versos cujo contexto é "guerra", estou ocupado com o seguinte: "Dung it about with enginery of war".

Comment: Tens certeza que não é o passado de *ding*? Da tradução, *adubar*, *estrumar* ou *fertilizar*. Eu não sou tradutor, mas talvez: literal "suas carcaças apodrecidas adubam o solo", ou "suas carcaças jazem podres no chão", já que *jazer* tem uma idéia parecida.

Comment: Sim, eu acho que é esta a metáfora: matou-se tanta gente que o campo foi "adubado" com os corpos. Eu nunca vi "adubar" usado em português nessa metáfora, porém. Às vezes alguma pessoa mais experiente pode trazer uma alternativa.

Comment: Pedro, também não, conquanto a única coisa parecida que já li seja a Demanda do Santo Graal, mas acho que o significado é bem óbvio. Um uso parecido é na música *Morte* do Raul Seixas: "Que meu corpo seja cremado e que minhas cinzas alimentem a erva/E que a erva alimente outro homem como eu".

Comment: Pedro, bem-vindo ao site. e obrigado e parabéns pelo cuidado com que explicaste o que procuras, com a definição do Oxford e isso tudo. Em perguntas que pedem uma tradução, é também útil indicares palavras que já consideraste mas que não te agradam e explicar porque é que não te agradam, para não estarmos a propor soluções que já tenhas rejeitado. Por exemplo, eu poderia responder com *estrumar* e *estercar*, mas imagino que já tenhas pensado nestas palavras, não?

Comment: Eu entendo que verbos no campo semântico do "adubo" são todos razoáveis. Eu me pergunto se por acaso existe algum que seja usado nessa metáfora em particular. Possivelmente algo tão preciso não existe.

Comment: Pedro, ok, o uso de algo como "estercar" mas aplicado a cadáveres. Olha, eu só vi a tua resposta ao meu comentário por acaso. Para notificares o a pessoa escreve @ + nome. Por exemplo, isto, @Schilive, vai avisar o Schilive deste comentário, e eu aproveito para lhe explicar (e a ti) que isto só funciona se a pessoa já tiver participado aqui nesta thread (a chamada do Schilive à Lambie lá em cima não funciona porque ela não esteve aqui). Para ti, Pedro, não é preciso: o autor do post é avisado de tudo o que aqui aconteça.

Comment: dung can be verbed. It just means the dead bodies will be fertilize the oranges trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No uso literal [*estercar* (Aulete)](https://www.aulete.com.br/estercar) e [*estrumar* (Aulete)](https://www.aulete.com.br/estrumar) são equivalente ao verbo [*dung* (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dung) no sentido ’espalhar esterco ou estrume (excrementos, normalmente misturados com matéria vegetal) na terra para a fertilizar’. Os vários dicionários que consultei não registam o uso de *estercar* ou *estrumar* a propósito de cadáveres caídos por terra, mas eu encontrei *estrumar* com esse uso na literatura. Eis [Jorge Amado em *O Menino Grapiúna*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=VrnuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cad%C3%A1veres%20estrumavam%22&dq=%22cad%C3%A1veres%20estrumavam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNrfjqnKHzAhWQohQKHWGTAr4Q6AF6BAgCEAI), a propósito das lutas sangrentas na Bahia, creio que no início do ciclo do cacau:

> Pagos numa tabela alta, os jagunços de tiro certeiro tinham regalias. As cruzes demarcavam o caminho do alardeado progresso da região, **os cadáveres estrumavam os cacauais**.

Ou este excerto d’[O Apologista Christão Brazileiro (Belém do Pará, 1899; grafia original)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=821055&pesq=%22estrumado%20com%20os%20cad%C3%A1veres%22&pasta=ano%20189&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=44):

> Essa região já tinha sido o theatro de muitas batalhas, e ainda testemunhou por diversas vezes o choque de grandes exercitos; seu solo foi muitas vezes **estrumado com os cadaveres** de assyrios, egypcios, israelitas […]

Há um exemplo do mesmo tipo no [Malho (Rio de Janeiro, 1905)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=116300&pesq=%22estrumado%20com%20os%20cad%C3%A1veres%22&pasta=ano%20190&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=3969); e num uso algo diferente, [Aquilino Ribeiro em *Terras do Demo* (1927)](https://pdfcoffee.com/aquilino-ribeiro-terras-do-demo-pdf-free.html):

> O Maneto foi-lhes no encalço [dos arruaceiros], forte daquela debandada, e, mal alcançou um dos arruaceiros, deu, deu até **o estrumar por terra**.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Uma opção com esse nível de precedente vai me ajudar muito!

Comment: "Estrumar" é comummente usado na gíria portuense (nortenha?) com esse sentido do último exemplo, de estar deitado mas em condições deploráveis. "Um moinante estrumado à entrada da Rua Escura", "a meio da festa dei por 3 deles estrumados no jardim ao lado de uma poça de vómito", etc.

Comment: @ANeves, eu não conhecia esse uso. Mas o Aquilino Ribeiro era lá dos lados de Viseu... Então ali, *estrumar* possivelmente significará simplesmente ’derrubar’?

Comment: @ANeves, pois, estive a ler o contexto: o tipo ainda recebeu a "a extrema unção e esteve a bater a bota", mas, "sem que ficasse escorreito, escapou".